# WebSphere: how to redirect user to the page he was before login?

Tags: mod-rewrite, websphere

I have portlet applications deployed on Websphere.

Сurrently if the user's session has expired and he logged in again, WebSphere redirects him to "Welcome to IBM WebSphere Portal x.x" page. How can i force it to go back to a previous page?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set redirect.login.url in the Configuration Service?

Answer (score 0):

If your user logs out, then you would normally have some code that deletes his user sessions (could be in the action of deleting a cookie), and then redirect him to the index page.

If you are talking about a user being on some page which is not the index page, then he logs in, and you want him to be redirected to the same page he was before logging in, you would have to save where he was before logging in.

This could be done in various ways. I would probably just have a cookie, that I update with some textfield indicating which site the user was previously on, and redirect the user to that page.

E.G. User visits SomePage.php - Before returning SomePage.php you update a field in his cookie "PreviousPage" = SomePage.php. Then after user logs in, you redirect him to "SomePage.php".

Answer (score 0):

In a default, configuration websphere redirects the user to default page/or the first page the page hierarchy which is determined by the portal. U have manually update the redirect.login.url property in config engine/config service and set redirect.login as true before you do that.

Refer: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYJ99_8.0.0/admin/srvcfgref_config.html

Note: Not sure which version you are using but I believe these would be available in previous as well as latest versions.